# After upgrade to Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After Upgrade to Rails4 I am getting warning below how can i fix that

```
.../gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: already initialized constant #<Module:0xbc58784>::AttrNames
.../gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:103: warning: previous definition of AttrNames was here
```

Please Help Me. 
My Functionality is working is fine but I don't want warning in my app so how can i fix that.

Comment: Perhaps had put in some monkey patches and forgotten about them?

Comment: Is your rails application called `AttrNames` and you also have a model called `AttrNames`? (would be weird, because it is plural, but it would give that error).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by an old gem. For example an old version of ActiveAdmin caused similar warnings. Many old gems are not fully compatible with Rails 4.

To update gems run `bundle update` and make sure that in the Gemfile there are no old versions specified.

Comment: So try to disable gem after gem to find out the guilty one.